# Conditionally retain

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, retain

I need to create a new variable, called `new_id`, which displays the same value for either same `id` `tasks` or same `location` `tasks`. In this example:

```
Table 1
id Task location
a Task1 lat1
b Task2 lat2 
b Task3 lat1
c Task4 lat3
c Task5 lat4
d Task6 lat5
e Task7 lat5



Table want
id Task Location New_id
a Task1 lat1     a
b Task2 lat2     a
b Task3 lat1     a 
c Task4 lat3     c
c Task5 lat4     c
d Task6 lat5     d
e Task7 lat5     d
```

- `Task1` and `Task3` must have the same `new_id` because they have the same `location`.
- `Task2` and `Task3` must have the same `new_id` because they have the same `id`.

I tried to use a `retain` `data step`.  First I sort on location, retain the first.variable, then sort id, retain the first.variable.

```
proc sort data=table1;
    by location;
data table1_1;
    set table1;
    by location;

    retain new_id_temp;
    if first.location then new_id_temp =id; 
    new_id=new_id_temp;
run;

proc sort data=table1_1;
    by id;
data table1_2;
    set table1_1;
    by id;

    retain id_temp;
    if first.id then id_temp=id; 
    new_id=id_temp;
run;
```

Based on the above code, I still got two different `new_id` and `proc sort` takes lots time if the datasets are large.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please extend your example, so we see when the `new_id` should change too

Comment: Very interesting question, but I agree with @Dirk, providing more data showing the need for new id's would help.

Comment: In the meantime.... there are ways to make `proc sort` run faster depending on how you plan on using the data, and the structure of your existing data.  Look into the `tagsort` option. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p02bhn81rn4u64n1b6l00ftdnxge.htm

Comment: Thanks @Dirk. I added more data

Comment: Wat is task8 would have id a again?

Comment: @DirkHorsten No. The id will not be duplicated

Comment: So the original id will always increment and my question was irrelevant, but what if `task8` will have `id` `f` and `location` `lat2`, for instance? Will it have `new_id` `f` or `a`?

Comment: And how many tasks could receive the same `new_id`? It makes a difference if that is a few hundred or a few million.

Comment: This is a graph theoretical problem and should be resolved with appropriate tools. I don't know of any SAS technique doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you didn't update the second datastep to use `new_id` as the source for the retained ID, so it's using `b` not `a`.

```
data table1_2;
set table1_1;
by id;
retain id_temp;
if first.id then 
  id_temp=new_id; 
new_id_fin=id_temp;
run;
```

I'm not sure this is really an effective way to solve your problem generally, but it should give you the results you want.  You might want to search around the site (or the web) for other ways to solve this problem, as it's a well understood but complex issue.

Comment: This fails in the same way as the answer from @Dominic: when I insert a location for b that sorts before the first location of a, the program does not discover a and b have a location in common.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results you expect, **with a caveat**: If you were to add a Task8 having id F and location lat1, you'd need a more refined algorithm with 2 or more passes. But this solution will work fine as long as your id's and locations progress in a way that elements sharing common id's and/or locations are placed after one another.

### Generate Sample Dataset

```
data tasks;
  input id $ Task $ location $;
  datalines;
a Task1 lat1
b Task2 lat2 
b Task3 lat1
c Task4 lat3
c Task5 lat4
d Task6 lat5
e Task7 lat5
;
```

### Generate all Possible Combinations using `PROC FREQ`

```
proc freq data=tasks;
  table id * task * location / out=combinations (drop=percent count);
run;
```

### Calculate New ID's Based on Your Criteria

```
data newIDs;
  set combinations;
  length prev_id $ 1
         newID $ 1
         prev_location $ 4;
  retain newID prev_id prev_location;

  * First scenario - first row;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
    put _N_= "First scenario - first row";
    newID = id;
    output;
    prev_id = id;
    prev_location = location;
  end;

  * Second scenario - some redundancy between 2 rows;
  else if id = prev_id or prev_location=location then do;
    put _N_= "Second Scenario - some redundancy";
    output;
    prev_id = id;
    prev_location = location;
  end;

  * Third scenario - no redundancy;
  else do;
    put _N_= "Third scenario - no redundancy";
    newID = id;
    output;
    prev_id = id;
    prev_location = location;
  end;

  keep id task location newID;

run;
```

### Merge the `Tasks` Dataset to the `newIDs` Dataset

```
proc sql;
  create table tasks_update as
    select  t.id
           ,i.newID
           ,t.Task
           ,t.location
      from tasks as t
        left join newIDs as i
               on t.id = i.id
                  and t.task = i.task
                  and t.location = i.location
      order by id;
quit;
```

### Results

```
id newID Task  location 
a  a     Task1 lat1 
b  a     Task2 lat2 
b  a     Task3 lat1 
c  c     Task4 lat3 
c  c     Task5 lat4 
d  d     Task6 lat5 
e  d     Task7 lat5
```

Comment: Thanks. @ Dominic But, the ideal results are the Tasks3 and Task4 have the newid= c and Tasks5-7 have the newid=d. how to adjust your code in order to get the ideal results?

Comment: You're welcome. It just requires a few little touch-ups, I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Testing your solution with the below data, I did not get the desired result:
`a Task1 lat1` \n
`b Task2 lat2` \n
`b Task3 lat1` \n
`b Task4 lat0` \n
`c Task5 lat3` \n
`c Task6 lat4` \n
`d Task7 lat5` \n
`e Task8 lat5` \n
`f Task9 lat1` _(I use \n to indicate a new line)_

Comment: Yes, this is the caveat I was referring to. See the intro to my answer. A fully working solution would involve some recursivity or graph-type tools as you mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

/*To help you understand the algorithm, I print intermediate results*/

```
%let print_diagnostics = 1; * 0 : no diagnostics 1 : diagnostics *;
```

/*Read in the example, extended with extra data*/

```
options mprint;

title read input data;
data table1;
  input id $ Task $ location $;
  datalines;
a Task01 lat1
b Task02 lat2
b Tas0k3 lat1
b Task04 lat0
c Task05 lat3
c Task06 lat4
d Task07 lat5
e Task08 lat5
f Task09 lat4
f Task10 lat6
g Task11 lat6
g Task12 lat7
h Task13 lat7
;
proc print;
run;
```

/*The solution needs some iteration, so we need a macro*/

```
%macro re_identify (got, want);
    * Initially, we assign id to new_id *;
    data &want.;
        set &got.;
        new_id = id;
    run;

    * proceed re-assigning ids until stabilised *;
    %let pass = 0;
    %let proceed = 1;
    %do %while (&proceed);
```

/*To lookup the smallest new_id already used for an id or location, I use hash tables. For more information, read [Data Step Hash Objects as Programming Tools](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/236-30.pdf)*/

```
        * We will construct two hash tables 
        * one with the smallest new_id for each id and *
        * one with the smallest new_id for each location *
        * To achieve this, the smallest new_id should come first *;
        %let pass = %eval(&pass + 1);
        title pass &pass;
        proc sort data=&want.;
            by new_id;
        run;

        data 
            %if &print_diagnostics %then %do;
                 hash_id(keep=id id_id)
                 hash_loc(keep=location loc_id)
             %end;
             &want. (drop=rc loc_id id_id proceed);
```

/*The hash tables have to be loaded only once of course. Mind the declaration of the data variables!*/

```
             * Create hash tables with for each id and location 
             * the smallest new_id used up to now *;
            length loc_id id_id $ 1;
            if _N_ eq 1 then do;
                dcl hash h_id (dataset: "&want.(rename=(new_id=id_id))");
                h_id.defineKey('id');
                h_id.definedata('id_id','id');
                h_id.defineDone();

                dcl hash h_loc (dataset: "&want.(rename=(new_id=loc_id))");
                h_loc.defineKey('location');
                h_loc.definedata('loc_id','location');
                h_loc.defineDone();

                * Unless we have to lower the new id for any id or location, 
                * we can stop after this pass *;
                proceed = 0;
            end;
            retain proceed;

            * Read in the data *;
            set &want. end=last;

            * If there is a task with the same id or location
            * with a smaller new_id, lower the new_id for this task *;
            rc = h_id.find() + h_loc.find();
            if rc then put 'WARNING: location not found' _all_;
            if id_id lt new_id then new_id = id_id;
            if loc_id lt new_id then new_id = loc_id;
            output &want.;

            * If we lowered the new_id, 
            * adapt the hash table 
            * and proceed after this pass *;
            if id_id gt new_id then do;
                id_id = new_id;
                h_id.replace();
                proceed = 1;
            end;
            if loc_id gt new_id then do;
                loc_id = new_id;
                h_loc.replace();
                proceed = 1;
            end;
```

/*Adapting the hashtables with the replace statement is optional but can drastically reduce the number of passes.*/

```
            * transfer the the decision to proceed 
            * from a data step variable to a macro variable *;
            if last then call symput ('proceed', proceed);

            %if &print_diagnostics %then %do;
                if last then do;
                    dcl hiter i_id ('h_id') ; 
                    dcl hiter i_loc ('h_loc') ; 
                    do rc = i_id.first () by 0 while ( rc = 0 ) ;
                        output hash_id;
                        rc = i_id.next () ;
                    end;
                    do rc = i_loc.first () by 0 while ( rc = 0 ) ;
                        output hash_loc;
                        rc = i_loc.next () ;
                    end; 

                    put "NOTE: after pass &pass." proceed=;
                end;
            %end;
        run;

        %if &print_diagnostics %then %do;
            * Print intermediate results *;
            title2 new id assigned to task;     proc print data=&want.;   run;
            title2 new id assigned to id;       proc print data=hash_id;  run;
            title2 new id assigned to location; proc print data=hash_loc; run;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend;

%re_identify(table1, table_want);
```

/*And finally write out the report.*/

```
* sort in task order and print the final results *;
title final result;
proc sort data=table_want;
    by Task;
proc print;
run;
```

/*
*/